# nohup for child process in unix

Tags: unix, shell, aix

If I nohuped a parent process in unix, will the spawned child processes have the same protection as their parent?.

Suppose,

```
nohup par-process.sh &
```

and if `par-process.sh` contains the call to child as,

```
par-child.sh
```

will par-child be nohuped or should I do that explicitly for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `man fork` child's signal handlers are inherited from parent, so answer to your question is *yes*.

Comment: You also have to read the exec() man page but in this case it works.